# C++ reading space in cin>> while receiving integers

Tags: c++

Example:

```
int main() {
    int areacode, phone;
    cout << "please  enter area code and phone #: " << endl;
    cin>> areacode, phone;
    cout<<"you entered ("<<areacode<<") "<< phone<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the output required is you entered: (416) 666-1111. Also area code and phone # have to be validated separately i.e #define minAreacode 100    maxAreacode 999 etc.  hence the phone # may not be taken as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> cin>> areacode, phone;
>            // ^
> ```

You are a victim of the comma operator letting your code compile, while it absolutely doesn't do what you want. The right side of `areacode`, is just ignored by the `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const std::string&)` operator.

You probably want to write

```
cin >> areacode >> phone;
```

Comment: While you're probably right with regards to what he meant to do... `std::cin >> areacode, phone` is `(std::cin >> areacode), phone`, so he'll still read the `areacode`.  (It's not clear to me what the input should look like; there's a good chance that he'll have to read it as a string, then parse the string to extract the values.  And of course, regardless of what he has to do, he shouldn't use the input until after verifying that it worked.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
cin >> areacode, phone;
```

Your code should read

```
cin >> areacode >> phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [cin.getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) and parse the input.